# send email using java spring and GMail

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to send an email using Spring and GMail. However, the email is not getting sent. I'm not receiving any errors. Below is my setup:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailS enderImpl">
 <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
 <property name="port" value="256"/>
 <property name="username" value="MyUsername"/>
 <property name="password" value="MyPassword"/>
 <property name="javaMailProperties">
<props>
    <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
</props>
```

```
 <bean id="userDefServiceTarget"
    class="com.xxx.setups.userdef.business.UserDefMgr" >
    <property name="mailSender"><ref local="mailSender"/></property>
  </bean>
```

**In my UserDefMgr class :**

```
  public void postMail()
{
  SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage() ;
  message.setSentDate(new Date()) ;
  message.setSubject("Test") ;
  message.setText("My First email. from java") ;
  message.setFrom("test@xx.com") ;
  mailSender.send(message) ;
 }
```

**What am I doing wrong? It's going thru the method and has all of the properties when it executes the send method.**

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google mail SMTP server running on 465 port